# What Java Framework should I Learn First?

Tags: java, user-interface, frameworks

So I'm new in Java Language and I'm trying to learn how Application are built...
I can't search on google so I'm gonna ask here

What java GUI framework should i Learn first?

Comment: If you're new to Java, I'd suggest first to learn Java language itself altogether with what JDK provides. After that it all depends on what types of applications are you planning to do. You didn't provide any details. Are you planning to do desktop applications, server applications?

Comment: *"What Java Framework should I Learn First?"* - The one that you are going to need to use first.  If you don't know which one that is ... neither do we.

Comment: You can start by learning Swing, it is an old and dated GUI library built inside Java but it will teach you many things about how event based GUI's work and how you should write them. Have fun learning!

Comment: Search sister site, Software Recommendations Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

What kind of applications? Java can create different types of applications. But since java is known for android development then i guess this is what you want to learn about java. Before learning anything about java applications it's recommended you start with java basics. And if in any way you will need to develop android apps with java then Google doesn't recommend java anymore. Kotlin is recommended for android development since it doesn't need you to write too much lines of code.